# Suggest new Stack Overflow Podcast Constitution Amendment without Twitter

Tags: discussion, podcast, constitution-amendment

Each week, the Stack Overflow Podcast proposes an amendment to the (fictional) Stack Overflow Constitution and requests "Pro" or "Con" votes via Twitter.

I would love to be able to suggest constitution amendments to the SO Constitution, but I don't have a Twitter account. Is there any other way to suggest an amendment?

Comment: Dunno.  Doesn't feel like it'd be a good fit for Meta either, and using Twitter allows them a convenient way to tally the results.

Comment: posting a poll on-site would allow an equally useful way to tally results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We chose twitter as the avenue because it is so instant and convenient, as well as having all of the answers in one place, but it's totally cool that you would like to participate even without a twitter account. Feel free to email a PRO or CON vote (or an amendment suggestion) to podcast@stackoverflow.com and I will add it into the mix.

For fairness, please keep the answer to 140 characters, as part of the fun of it is trying to be funny AND pithy. Thanks for listening!

Comment: Perhaps you could add a script, like the "Contact Us" form, that allows users to email a 140-character-limited submission like the comment form.